# I'd like to display a header as 100% width on browser with Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'd like to display the black header as 100% of browser, but when I make the browser wide and narrow, the header is not showed as 100% width.
[image]
You can see it in this photo.
[image]
How should I change or add css code?
My site is [here](https://bananaman.herokuapp.com/header/).

Sorry, I forgot to write my code. My code is following this.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $affix = $('*[data-spy="affix"]');
    $affix.width($affix.parent().width());
  });
```

```css
html {
  font-size: 62.5% !important;  /* 10 px */
}

/*header {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  top: 0px;
  z-index: 1000;
  color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  height: 64px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.07);
}*/

.carousel-control.left, .carousel-control.right {
  background: none !important;
  filter: progid: none !important;
  outline: 0;
}
.carousel .carousel-control {
  visibility: hidden;
}
.carousel:hover .carousel-control {
  visibility: visible;
}
.carousel-indicators {
  bottom:-50px;
}
.carousel-inner {
  margin-bottom:50px;
}

/*.logo {
  float: left;
  text-align: left;
  display: inline-block;
}*/

.transparent-header {
  z-index: 22;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.07);
}

#carousel-example-generic {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.nav::after,
.nav::before,
.navbar-header::after,
.navbar::after {
  display: table-caption;
}

.nav.navbar-nav li,
.nav.navbar-nav li a {
  display: inline-block;
}

#gnav {
  font-size: 0.9em;
  /*width: 100%;*/
}

#logo 
  img {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-EN">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">  <!-- for IE --> 
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0"> 
  <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
  <meta name=”robots” content=”noindex,nofollow,noarchive,noodp,noydir”>
<!--  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.min.css"> -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css' %}" />
  {% block additional_css %}{% endblock %}
  {% block custom_css %}{% endblock %}
</head>
<body>

<div id="wrapper">

  <!-- <div class="container" id="range">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3" style="background-color:Yellow;">ExtraSmall</div>
      <div class="hidden-xs col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3" style="background-color:green;">Small</div>
      <div class="hidden-xs hidden-sm col-md-4 col-lg-3" style="background-color:blue;">Midium</div>
      <div class="hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md col-lg-3" style="background-color:Red;">Large</div>
    </div>
  </div> -->

  <!-- Header -->
  <header id="header" class="header clearfix fixed transparent-header" >
    <div class="container-fluid" id="header-inner">
      <div class="row">

        <!-- Global Navigation -->
        <div id="gnav" class="" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="94">
          <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" id="">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="dropdown">
                  <a class="" data-toggle="dropdown" href="index.html">商品紹介</a>
                  <!-- Dropdown -->
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li>
                      <a class="" href='#'>ジュース <i class=""></i></a>
                      <ul class="sub-dropdown">
                        <li><a href="#">オレンジ</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">アップル</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">グレープ</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a class="" href='#'>寿司 <i class=""></i></a>
                      <ul class="sub-dropdown">
                        <li><a href="#">マグロ</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">サーモン</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">エンガワ</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                  </ul>  <!-- dropdown-menu -->
                </li>  <!-- .dropdown -->

                <li class="dropdown">
                  <a class="" data-toggle="dropdown" href="index.html">ご注文</a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li>
                      <a class="" href='#'>スマートフォン <i class=""></i></a>
                      <ul class="sub-dropdown">
                        <li><a href="#">iPhone</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Xperia</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Galaxy</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a class="" href='#'>野菜 <i class=""></i></a>
                      <ul class="sub-dropdown">
                        <li><a href="#">トマト</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">レタス</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">枝豆</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                  </ul>  <!-- dropdown-menu -->
                </li>  <!-- .dropdown -->

                <li class="dropdown">
                  <a class="" data-toggle="dropdown" href="index.html">お問い合わせ</a> 
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a class="" href='#'>自分用</a></li>
                    <li><a class="" href='#'>他人用</a></li>
                  </ul>  <!-- dropdown-menu -->
                </li>  <!-- .dropdown -->

                <li class="dropdown">
                  <a class="" data-toggle="dropdown" href="index.html">会社案内</a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a class="" href='#'>フォーム</a></li>
                    <li><a class="" href='#'>電話</a></li>
                  </ul>  <!-- dropdown-menu -->
                </li>  <!-- dropdown -->

              </ul>  <!-- .nav .navbar-nav -->

          </nav>  <!-- .navbar .navbar-default  -->
        </div>  <!-- #gnav .col-md-9 -->

        <!-- Logo -->
        <div id="logo" class="">
          <a href="#">
            <img src="http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/logopedia/images/e/ee/Burger_King_Logo.svg.png/revision/20120422044236" id="logo-img" class="img-responsive logo-img" height="50" width="50">
          </a>
        </div>  <!-- #logo .col-sm-3 -->

      </div>  <!-- .row -->
    </div>  <!-- .container -->
  </header>  <!-- #header .clearfix -->


  <section id="">
    <article id="apple">
        <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
          <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
          </ol>
          <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
            <div class="item active">
              <img class="melon img-responsive" src="http://htmlcoder.me/preview/the_project/v.1.3/template/images/slider-fullscreen-slide-1.jpg" alt="First slide">
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <img class="melon img-responsive" src="http://htmlcoder.me/preview/the_project/v.1.3/template/images/slider-fullscreen-slide-2.jpg" alt="Second slide">
            </div>
          </div>
          <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="icon-prev" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
          </a>
          <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="icon-next" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div>
          <span>Bootstrap carousel</span>
        </div>
    </article>
  </section>

  <h1><span>I LOVE TOMATO!!!!</span></h1><br>
  <h1><span>I LOVE TOMATO!!!!</span></h1><br>
  <h1><span>I LOVE TOMATO!!!!</span></h1><br>
  <h1><span>I LOVE TOMATO!!!!</span></h1><br>
  <h1><span>I LOVE TOMATO!!!!</span></h1><br>
  <h1><span>I LOVE TOMATO!!!!</span></h1><br>
  <h1><span>I LOVE TOMATO!!!!</span></h1><br>
  <h1><span>I LOVE TOMATO!!!!</span></h1><br>
  <h1><span>I LOVE TOMATO!!!!</span></h1><br>
  <h1><span>I LOVE TOMATO!!!!</span></h1><br>
  <h1><span>I LOVE TOMATO!!!!</span></h1><br>
  <h1><span>I LOVE TOMATO!!!!</span></h1><br>
  <h1><span>I LOVE TOMATO!!!!</span></h1><br>



</div>  <!-- #wrapper -->
  
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.min.js"></script> -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
  </html>
```

Comment: give me your code snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i can see, you are setting width with jquery, so you need jquery on resize to fit again the full width:

```
$( window ).resize(function() {
    var $affix = $('*[data-spy="affix"]');
    $affix.width($affix.parent().width());
});
```

Change this line of code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $affix = $('*[data-spy="affix"]');
    $affix.width($affix.parent().width());
});
```

to:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var $affix = $('*[data-spy="affix"]');
        $affix.width($affix.parent().width());
        $( window ).resize(function() {
            var $affix = $('*[data-spy="affix"]');
            $affix.width($affix.parent().width());
        });
});
```

Comment: Thank you, Ultrazz008. There is a bug in `Bootstrap Affix`, so I wrote that jQuery code. And I couldn't notice it caused the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

```html
/** Full Width Header CSS **/
#gnav{
  width: 100%!important;
}
```

This css fix your header issue.

Comment: AH!!! Thank you for your answer, Goutam Singha. It seems this is the easiest way even for `Bootstrap Affix Bug`. I couldn't come up with this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You may try to use `vw` (viewport width) units on you header. For more information, you can read [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/length#Viewport-percentage_lengths)

Answer (score 0):

Create custom css file and write your css code here, custom css should be below of bootstrap.css

like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="boostrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="custom.css">
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice, Val.